# Блокирование/разблокирование потока из другого потока по событию

Tags: java, многопоточность, очередь

Здравствуйте,

Есть задача (**Task**)

Есть очередь (**Queue**, блокирующая приоритетная очередь)

Есть менеджер очереди (**QueueManager**)

Есть обработчик очереди (**QueueHandler**)

*QueueManager* - синглтон.

**Task**, среди прочего, имеет такую характеристику как желаемое время выполнения (`desired_at_ts`). В этом поле указано время, не раньше которого должна быть выполнена данная задача. Это поле участвует в компараторе, на его основе вычисляется приоритет задачи в очереди.

**QueueManager** инициализирует очередь, предоставляет методы `put()`/`take()` и другие, которые в данный момент не важны.

**QueueHandler** реализует интерфейс `Runnable`. *QueueHandler* в бесконечном цикле обрабатывает очередь **Queue**.

- **QueueHandler** проверяет - наступило ли время, указанное в `desired_at_ts`
- если время пришло - выполняет задачу.
- если время не пришло, **QueueHandler** должен положить задачу обратно
- цикл повторяется.

Теперь то, что я хочу узнать:

Если время `desired_at_ts` не наступило, **QueueHandler** кладет задачу обратно в очередь. Так как очередь приоритетная - понятно, что эта задача попадет в начало очереди; и при следующем цикле из очереди будет получена она же. Ожидание наступления времени

```
time = desired_at_ts - now_ts
```

может быть реализовано методом `wait(long ms)`. Но так как **QueueManager** может добавить в очередь новую задачу в любой момент, новая задача может иметь `desired_at_ts` ближе к текущему времени, чем та задача, которая только что была возвращена обратно в очередь. Поток **QueueHandler** надо пробуждать в тот момент, когда отработает компаратор очереди и задача будет поставлена на свое место по приоритету. Вопросы:

1. Где должен быть размещен код, пробуждающий поток? В каком методе очереди/компаратора или чего то еще?
2. Как организовать такую блокировку? Я думаю, удобнее использовать `ReentrantLock` и `Condition` от него. Но в этом случае объекты этих классов должны существовать в единственном экземпляре и должны будут передаваться из класса в класс. Это нормально?
3. Если есть комментарии/критика к описанному мною алгоритму - буду рад обсудить их.

Comment: я бы просто сделал обертку над очередью, которая не выдает элемент, пока не истек await на каком-нибудь синхронизаторе (этот await сбрасывается путем добавления нового элемента в обертку)

Comment: Посмотрите реализацию [`j.u.c.DelayQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) в JDK. Там один из ожидающих потоков получает сигнал пробуждения при добавлении, если новый элемент попал в начало очереди, и при выходе из `take`, если очередь не пуста. Ожидание и пробуждение потоков происходит в коде очереди, поэтому `ReentrantLock` никуда не передается.

Comment: **zRrr**, а как быть с приоритетом при использовании j.u.c.DelayQueue?

Comment: А, в этом случае *delay* и будет тем самым приоритетом. То, что надо

Answer (score 2):

*Из комментария пользователя [@zRrr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190934/zrrr):*

Посмотрите реализацию [`j.u.c.DelayQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) в JDK. Там один из ожидающих потоков получает сигнал пробуждения при добавлении, если новый элемент попал в начало очереди, и при выходе из `take`, если очередь не пуста. Ожидание и пробуждение потоков происходит в коде очереди, поэтому `ReentrantLock` никуда не передается.